# xna: display 2d sprites behind the 3d object

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

i am a beginner in 3d graphics thing and learning xna and csharp.

i have 3d object that i want to draw in front of a 2d background,
the 3d object is simple, it is just a line. i made it from 2 dimensional VertexPositionColor[].

and then i drew it with PrimitiveType.LineStrip.

and also i have a Texture2D that i displayed with Spritebatch.draw.

what is happening is the line is displayed at the back of the background, so i cant see any line.

but if i commented the spritebatch.draw, i can see the line there.

please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a z-buffer problem there. In what order are you doing the 2D and 3D drawing? 2D should come first I would guess. Also, you should check out [how to make render states work](http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/1796.aspx) when mixing SpriteBatch and 3D operations.

Comment: i thought that too. when i applied the code, still it didnt affect anything

Answer (score 1):

i managed to fix it.
all the 3D draw method should be after spritebatch.begin and end.

what i did was put the effect.begin and pass.begin after the spritebatch.begin and end

here are the code for the draw method on game1.cs(the default filename when you use the wizard)

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        spriteBatch.Begin();             
        GameEngine.Draw(GameEngine,gameTime); 
        spriteBatch.End();

        //resetRenderState3D();
        GameEngine.Draw3D(GameEngine, gameTime);

        base.Draw(gameTime); 
    }
```

Comment: So what you're basically saying is that my answer was correct..? ;)

Comment: yeah it was correct. lol. but after some changing in the code, i had to apply(uncomment the resetRenderState3D) the  reset render state again.
weird.. but it s worked.

Comment: Good. Yes, weird. Perhaps letting the sprite batch save render state will have the same effect as resetting render state...

Comment: as the article said, saverenderstate will slow the game. even without it my game is already slow. i think i have to do some trick here and there.